# Interstitial Ads by Admob doesnt show up

Tags: android, admob, show, interstitial

**EDIT:** The ImageButton play is used to start new activity and i want it to load the interstitial ad afther i click on it and it should show the Ad before the activity. Please help me to edit this code. I am completely lost...

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

private InterstitialAd interstitial;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.loadingscreen);

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(Intro.this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("F7D422E96C746A6BB1D1DB432FEA62C6")
            .build();

    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });

    ImageButton play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.mycompany.FattyPillow.MAINPAGE"));
        }
    });


}

public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Strongly suggest you **DON'T** call `interstitial.show()` from `onAdLoaded()`, unless you *want* to piss off your users AND get you Admob account banned.

Comment: I will think about these stuff right afther i get my Ads working properly :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all recheck your `AdUnitId`, confirm it, it should be accurate.
2. `.addTestDevice("aaa")` here 'aaa' is invalid value for test device. Run app with Admob code and see your logs, you will see `addTestDevice` with valid id of the device on which you ran app.
3. Your code looks fine, If still ad doesn't load see logs and post it in your question.

> This Acutally should show the Ad as soon as this Activy starts right?

No, Admob will start loading ad as soon as activity starts, and when it finishes loading ad only then it will display ad.

Comment: I Edited the code and i found my TestDeviceID and AdUnitId is testing Id not mine. And it still doesn't show the Ad neithe in my phone or in Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your logs, they will tell you exactly what is going on with Admob.

If you want to show the interstitial *after* the user clicks on the button, but *before* your show your new Activity then you are going to have to:

1. Call `interstitial.show()` on button click.
2. In your `AdListener.onAdClosed()` call startActivity for new Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The issue was that admob activity was not defined in manifest. Please make sure you have folllowing activity tag in your manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```